# How to send mail text with image in compose mail body

Tags: android

I am not able to view the image in mail body. Its just appearing like dotted small box.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.mailshare);
    send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    address = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailaddress);
    //subject = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailsubject);
  //  emailtext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null) {
        String emailtitle = extras.getString(TEXT_DATA);
        if(emailtitle != null) {
             subject = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailsubject);
            if(subject != null) {
                subject.setText(emailtitle);
            }
        }
    }

    Bundle mailmsg = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(mailmsg != null) {
        String bodytext = mailmsg.getString(BODY_TEXT);
        if(bodytext != null) {
              emailtext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
            if(subject != null) {
                emailtext.setText(bodytext);
            }
        }
    }

    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            [enter link description here][2]//                  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ address.getText().toString()});
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.getText());
            emailIntent.setType("image/png"); 

            Spanned html =Html.fromHtml("<html><body> <img src='http://www.example.com/logo.png'> </body></html>",

                    new ImageGetter() {

                     InputStream s;
                     public Drawable getDrawable(String url) {

                      try {
                       s = (InputStream) (new URL(url)).getContent();
                      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                       e.printStackTrace();
                      } catch (IOException e) {

                     e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(s, null);
                  //  Log.debug(this, "Got image: " + d.getClass() + ", " + d.getIntrinsicWidth() + "x" + d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    return d;
                    }},null);
                 //   emailIntent.putExtra(emailIntent.EXTRA_TEXT, html);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, html);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));



        }   
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Hi  i did by the following code...

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
            int resId = mSmileyToRes.get(matcher.group());
            builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(mContext, resId), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}



(Editable) editMessageText.setText ( builder );
```

Comment: This code is used for append smile text but not an image(.png,.jpeg), can u rewrite the above code for append image in mail body

Answer (score 1):

I used SpannableStringBuilder and ImageSpan for adding smileys to the text.

Comment: Hi Vikky, But I need to append the logo at the end of the text in mail body.  Is theere any method

Comment: Thank u vikky, I used above code as U said (Span Image), but not able to view